# How to print to barcode printer from windows-mobile 2005?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, zebra-printers

I need to print to barcode printer (zebra) from windows-mobile 2005 (motorola hc700)

I search any sdk...not fount how to print.

thank's for any help

Answer (score 5):

Check out the new mobile SDK from Zebra. It works with BlackBerry and Windows Mobile

[ZebraLink Multiplatform SDK](http://www.zebra.com/sdk)

Comment: That is for use with VS 2008; I need it for VS 2003. When I try to install the SDK (ZebraSDK1.0.121.exe), in either Windows 7 or XP Mode VM, I get, "Could not find a valid Java virtual machine to load.

You may need to reinstall a supported Java virtual machine."

Comment: the installer needs java to run... sorry :-(

Comment: At any rate, I don't think it would work with my setup for this project (Visual Studio 2003, .NET 1.1)

Answer (score 2):

**This is based on my experience from 2006.**

I had to use sockets in C# to send ZPL code to the printer.  The "ZPL Code Generator" was hard-coded specifically to the one label format we needed; however, a template file with strategically placed search-and-replace strings would have been a better solution.  There was a ZPL guide included with the printer and I'm sure you can get one from their website.

The Windows drivers were awful at the time and only produced garbage output.  A couple developers before me had other approaches and both failed after a few weeks.

Edit:

[Link to MSDN .Net Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b86d684.aspx).  When 

From my project, the port you should use is 6101.  But that may be specific to the QL320.

The ZPL guides from Zebra are pretty good and I had little reason to devote the language to memory because it was just one small project.

Also, your printer may use EPL instead of ZPL but Zebra's guide for that is equally good.  Either way, if the text you are sending to the printer is relatively constant, just create a  file that correctly prints when streamed to the printer and then put in "replace me" blocks for your app to put in the dynamic values.

I'm also assuming that you are accessing this via a network.  If your connecting it directly to the device, this changes slightly (I believe it gets mapped to COM port for most devices).

Answer (score 1):

All that, and no mention of

http://www.zebra.com/id/zebra/na/en/index/products/software/label_design_software/label_vista.html

We developed our label code by creating the labels in label vista and using telnet to send them to the printer for printing. Repeat until you have it like you want, then code it.